# How to minimize Rest API calls between microservices for one flow?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I'm working on the migration from monolithic to microservice architecture but I have few concerns regarding few of the functionalities. There is a getOrder API implemented in Order service and it internally calls 5 to 6 microservices APIs like inventory API, customer API and so on. Each microservice has its own database.

In this scenario, how to reduce the internal API calls to improve the performance ? Any design pattern to implement ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I would just advice to try to parallelize calls whenever it is possible to reduce the global processing time of the incoming request.